# Can't change Dropbox's Autoplay settings

Tags: windows-7, dropbox, autoplay

Every time I plug in my USB memory stick, Dropbox instantly starts scanning for and uploading photos from it.  I do not want it to do this and I want to get a Windows prompt upon any media being plugged into my computer.

I tried checking the Dropbox setting for an option, however it only links to Windows' autoplay control panel.

[image: Dropbox Settings Window]

When changing any setting in the Windows autoplay settings, it willrevert back to Dropbox being default immediatly after I have saved it.

[image: Windows Autoplay Settings]

How can I change this so that it will ask me what I want to do every time?

**EDIT:** This is the case on both of my Windows computers.

**EDIT2:** Disabling AutoPlay solves the problem but is not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ever since a recent update to Dropbox.  This problem has no longer been occurring.  I can successfully change the autoplay settings for Camera Upload's media types without them being reverted back.

Comment: Unfortunately, Dropbox puts itself as default selected option on the autorun choices prompt, which is actually just as annoying.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I changed my AutoPlay settings back.

Make sure "Mixed content" (and anything else autoplay with "Import pictures and videos using Dropbox") is set as "Take no action":

[image]

Also, setting "Mixed content" to "Take no action" will keep AutoPlay from opening when inserting a USB drive without disabling AutoPlay.

Comment: That field was still affected by the original bug.